# How to extract key value pairs using regular expression?

Tags: regex

Let's be honest, I'm struggling with the regular expression I need to extract parts of the character sequence. The sequence contains pairs of key and value pairs enclosed with `/` character. So the pair could be `/KEY/VALUE/`, but also `/KEY/VAL/UE/`. The pairs sits next to each other in the sequence.

Let's look at the example sequence:

> `/ABCD/value1//ECFG/value2//HIJK/value3a/value3b/`

What I'd like to be able to do is to get the list of the key value pairs like this:

> `ABCD -> value1`
>
> `ECFG -> value2`
>
> `HIJK -> value3a/value3b`

Comment: what language do you want to run this in?

Comment: I'm using Java, `java.util.regex.*` to be more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
/(.+?)/(.+?)/(?=/|$)
```

The first paren will capture the key, the second the value.
The lookahead matches either a 2nd `/`, indicating a new key/value pair or the string end for the last key/value pair.

Edit: Here some python code:

```
s = "/ABCD/value1//ECFG/value2//HIJK/value3a/value3b/"
re.findall('/(.+?)/(.+?)/(?=/|$)', s)
# [('ABCD', 'value1'), ('ECFG', 'value2'), ('HIJK', 'value3a/value3b')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `/(.*?)/(.*?)/`

Here's how you would use it with sed:

```
sed -e 's,/(.*?)/(.*?)/,$1 --> $2\n,g' inputfile.txt
```

The key is non-greedy matches `.*?` (instead of greedy `.*`)